# How to make two controls apear as focused?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I'm trying to write a custom control, that have a TextBox and a ListBox inside it's template.
But I've found that when I entering a text in the TextBox (so TextBox has focus), ListBox appears as not focused. This makes my control looks like two different controls.

I've read at MSDN that in the WPF there is something called FocusScope but I didn't succeed with it.

So my question is how can I make both ListBox and TextBox controls appear as focused when one of them has keyboard focus within?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `IsFocusScope` Property to the surrounding *Panel* (here: StackPanel):
The ListBox and the TextBox are treated together in regards of being focussed

```
  <StackPanel FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
    <ListBox >
      <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBox>Enter Text here...</TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: A focus scope works different. It defines the scope where exactly one element has the logical focus and when it is the active scope also the keyboard focus. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#focus for more detail.

Comment: I'm not mentioned that in my case ListBox is in Popup but TextBox isn't.